# Service account does not have storage.buckets.lists access to project while pushing images to GCR via Gitlab CI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, gcloud, google-cloud-repository

I am using Gitlab CI to build docker images and to push them to GCR. My Script goes like this -

```
build:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  cache:
  script:
    - echo "$GCP_SERVICE_KEY" > gcloud-service-key.json # Google Cloud service accounts
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - echo ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}
    - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 gcloud builds submit -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} .
  only:
    - master
```

and I am getting this error-

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: <service account name>@<projectname>.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project <projectid>.
```

After giving service account `Cloud Editor` permissions, I am getting the error -

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) User [<service account name>@<projectname>.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access b [<bucker_name>] (or it may not exist): <service account name>@<projectname>.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to <bucket_name>
```

What all permissions do I have to give to service account to achieve so?

Comment: From the docs (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-build-roles and https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-control#roles), it looks like `roles/
cloudbuild.builds.editor` is sufficient to submit builds. However, your error message states that `storage.buckets.list` permission is missing here, and this permission is not included in this role. But it is included in `roles/
cloudbuild.builds.builder`. What are the current roles/permissions given to your service account? Could you try with a SA with only Cloud Build Editor role?

Comment: I tried and now it is giving me `does not have storage.buckets.get access to <bucket_name>`

Comment: Is this a bucket you have created or an "internal" bucket?

Comment: Its name is <project_name>_cloudbuild. It can be deleted that means it was created by someone.

Comment: What operation do you perform in your dockerfile?

Comment: it is just dockerizing the react app and exposing the port. @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 1):

From the error:

```
<service account name>@<projectname>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
does not have storage.buckets.list access to project <projectid>
```

I suspect that `<projectname>` and `<projectid>` refer to 2 different projects.

The project that owns the service account (`<projectname>`) may well have `storage.[buckets|objects].*` permissions but these will apply to the GCS resources controlled by `<projectname>` and **not** to those controlled by `<projectid>`.

**NB** Yes, it's confusing to see projects referenced by different types of keys but, to confirm, compare the `ProjectID` of `<projectname>` with `<projectid>`. Replace `<projectname>` with its value in the below to retrieve the `ProjectID`:

```
gcloud projects list --filter="name=<projectname> --format="value(projectId)"
```

There are 2 approaches to permitting identities to access GCS resources. The first is (as above) to create these at the project level. The second is to apply these to specific buckets.

See the link below for guidance. It's for Cloud Build's service account but the principle is the same. The service account (in project `<projectname>`) needs to have access to the GCS resources in `<projectid>`:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#push_private_images_to_others