# Uploading Multiple Web Files to Cloud Storage With Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload multiple web files to a storage bucket using python. I have a service account set up to enable the credentials and so it should be working. However, every time I try to run this code I receive this error:

Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/voterfile-oh?projection=noAcl: xxx@yyy.zzz.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to voterfile-oh.

Can I receive help on this issue? I was not able to gather any helpful information from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513905/service-account-does-not-have-storage-buckets-lists-access-to-project-while-push) nor did the questioner receive an answer that resolved the issue.

```
def upload_voterfile(bucket_name):
    from google.cloud import storage
    from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
    import os
    import json

    credentials_dict = {credentials}
    with open('credentials.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(credentials_dict, json_file)

    credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('credentials.json')

    client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project='oh-data-pipeline')
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    county_list= ['Adams','Allen', 'Ashland', 'Ashtabula', 'Athens', 'Auglaize', 'Belmont', 'Brown', 'Butler', 'Carroll', 
                  'Champaign', 'Clark', 'Clermont', 'Clinton', 'Columbiana', 'Coshocton', 'Crawford', 'Cuyahoga', 'Darke', 
                  'Defiance', 'Delaware', 'Erie', 'Fairfield', 'Fayette', 'Franklin', 'Fulton', 'Gallia', 'Geauga', 'Greene', 
                  'Guernsey', 'Hamilton', 'Hancock', 'Hardin', 'Harrison', 'Henry', 'Highland', 'Hocking', 'Holmes', 
                  'Huron', 'Jackson', 'Jefferson', 'Knox', 'Lake', 'Lawrence', 'Licking', 'Logan', 'Lorain', 'Lucas', 'Madison',
                  'Mahoning', 'Marion', 'Medina', 'Meigs', 'Mercer', 'Miami', 'Monroe', 'Montgomery', 'Morgan', 'Morrow', 
                  'Muskingum', 'Noble', 'Ottawa', 'Paulding', 'Perry', 'Pickaway', 'Pike', 'Portage', 'Preble', 'Putnam', 
                  'Richland', 'Ross', 'Sandusky', 'Scioto', 'Seneca', 'Shelby', 'Stark', 'Summit', 'Trumbull', 'Tuscarawas', 
                  'Union', 'Van Wert', 'Vinton', 'Warren', 'Washington', 'Wayne', 'Williams', 'Wood', 'Wyandot']

    for f, g in zip(range(1, 89), county_list):
        file = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:{}'.format(f))
        blob = bucket.blob('{}'.format(g))
        blob.upload_from_string(data=file.read(), content_type="text/plain")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    upload_voterfile(bucket_name='voterfile-oh')
```

Comment: What roles have you assigned to `xxx@yyy.zzz.com` for the project that owns the bucket? Look this information up in the Google Cloud Console under IAM.

Comment: Just to add a bit onto @JohnHanley's comment... make sure the role(s) assigned to that service account have permission to the operations you need, such as storage.buckets.get. [This reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) is enormously helpful. Note that in GCS a writer role (like objectCreator) doesn't inherit read access, so it is possible to have svc accounts that can write but not read. You may need to also assign another role that has storage.buckets.get.

Comment: Alternatively, you may not need to call client.get_bucket() at all. That gets all the information about the bucket from the API. If it is only a means to creating a blob later, you should be able to [construct a Bucket object locally](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html) and use its blob() method. `bucket = Bucket(client, name=bucket_name)` or similar.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens. You can also edit out the info and flag your post for a moderator to redact the edit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce your issue, here are the steps I have followed:

1. Created a service account and assign Storage Object Creator permission.
2. Ran `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create [FILE_NAME].json --iam-account [NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com` to [get account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) file.
3. Erased lines 7 to 9 of your script and changed the filename of line 11 to match the name of the downloaded credentials file.
4. Ran the script. Here I get the same error as you.

The reason behind this error is that on line 14 you're getting your bucket object through `get_bucket` method. This [method](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html?highlight=get_bucket#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.get_bucket) queries cloud Storage, requiring get permissions on your bucket but the Storage Object Creator role does not include get permissions.

To solve your issue just change line 14 with this code `bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)` which directly creates a bucket object without interacting with Cloud Storage and therefore it does not raise the permission error, see corresponding [reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html?highlight=get_bucket#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.bucket).

Another solution might be to change the service account role to Storage Object Admin because it includes get permissions.